# How do I draw shape on the JPanel, also linking the shape with an event control?

Tags: java, user-interface

I've made a code to draw a simple oval in a panel and then according to the button clicked (left or right) or arrow button, it will move accordingly. This code I have here doesn't seem to make the shape appear in the yellow background. Is there anything that I can change?

Also, I will also link the made oval into two separate keyboard and button click events. Is using KeyAdaptor method and lambda expression on the mouse event a good measure here? Thank you in advance!

```
private JButton btnLeftMvmt, btnRightMvmt;

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        int width = getWidth()/2;
        int top = (getHeight() - HEIGHT) / 2; 
        /* Code above is a vain attempt to center the oval to the yellow 
        background. 
        Is this correct, as well?*/
        g.fillOval(width, top, 150, 150);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
    }
}

public MyFrame(){
    setTitle("Red Oval Translator");
    setSize(500, 200);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel panel1, panel2;

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel2 = new JPanel();

    panel1.add(new MyPanel());
    panel1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    btnLeftMvmt = new JButton("Left Translation");
    btnRightMvmt = new JButton("Right Translation");

    panel2.add(btnLeftMvmt);
    panel2.add(btnRightMvmt);

    add(panel1);
    add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Please post [mcve] . There is no `JFrame` in the code posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you wanted something like that:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public MyPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 250));
    }

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponents(g);
        int width = getWidth()/2;
        int top = (getHeight() - HEIGHT) / 2;
        g.setColor(Color.RED); //need to apply color before painting
        g.fillOval(width, top, 150, 150);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->new MyFrame());
    }
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame{

    private JButton btnLeftMvmt, btnRightMvmt;

    public MyFrame() {

        setTitle("Red Oval Translator");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout()); //BorderLayout for JFrame
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        btnLeftMvmt = new JButton("Left Translation");
        btnRightMvmt = new JButton("Right Translation");
        panel2.add(btnLeftMvmt);
        panel2.add(btnRightMvmt);

        add(new MyPanel());
        add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Always post [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you, but now I have a new problem on the oval itself where the oval doesn't appear in the center of the frame. Is there any parts that I have to change in the code?

Comment: After doing some customization, and with the help of others I finally finished it, thank you very much for your support and help!

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code is that you should swap the order of `g.fillOval(width, top, 150, 150);` and `g.setColor(Color.RED);` to get a red oval and not a default-colored oval.

Comment: "you overwrite btnLeftMvmt with btnRightMvmt since you're adding them to the same spot in the layout." No, you don't .  A `JPanel` uses `FlowLayout` by default.